# Crystal Reports for VS 2008 - "The user function manager DLL (ufmanager.dll) could not be found."

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, windows-server-2003, 64-bit

StackOverflow, you're my only hope!

I am unfortunate enough to have inherited an ASP.NET 3.5 application roughly 3/4 in development. This project uses Crystal Reports Basic for VS 2008 to generate a PDF file from a data source. Pretty straightforward.

Anyway, this project compiles and runs fine on my development machine (VS 2008), but then when I publish it to the server (which has the CR Basic for VS 2008 Runtime installed), I get this error message when trying to export the report to PDF:

```
Error in File C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\Report {D3596595-5217-4888-A770-72427B29DE27}.rpt:
The user function manager DLL (ufmanager.dll) could not be found.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error in File C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\Report {D3596595-5217-4888-A770-72427B29DE27}.rpt:
The user function manager DLL (ufmanager.dll) could not be found.
```

Unfortunately, a search on Google for the error message only turns up a handful of results, and they haven't helped.

My server is running Windows 2003 x64 SP2. I've tried installing the Crystal Reports runtimes on the server (both the x86 and x64 editions). Strangely enough, the app doesn't detect the x64 version, so I'm using the x86 version.

I see the file **ufmanager.dll** in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Common\2.8\bin**, but I don't know where my app is looking for it. I even tried sticking it in the "bin" folder of my app, but no luck.

If any kind soul happens to have seen this error before and knows the fix, I would be *seriously* grateful.

Comment: Given that the error appears to be a COM exception, does ufmanager.dll need to be registered on the server?

Comment: Does the report use a user-defined function (from an external DLL)?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure what data to insert in the server's registry, and where. I have found some information on this, but it was pertaining to Crystal Reports 10.
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1067657&page=1
I am using CR Basic 2008 (for VS). which is 10.5. Different registry entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing the runtime for Crystal Reports Basic for VS 2008?
Check my post on runtime locations at http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2008/12/crystal-reports-basic-2008-runtime.html

Remember that if you use the CR B for VS 2008 runtime, then you must update the dll versions from 10.2.x to 10.5.x (needs to be done in the web.config as well as the aspx files which use the CR viewer).

Comment: Yup, this is what I ended up having to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just spent two days on this error and was ready to pull my hair out.  The bottom line is that giving the IIS_WPG user full control permission on the crystal bin folder did it.  This is very similar to the famous unknown.rpt error on setting up crystal on a Windows 2003 server.

It's important to note that the Crystal support guys (I spoke with two of the absolute best) have never seen this error and it's only documented on the net once or twice.  We are all assuming that it's due to my using a Godaddy virtual dedicated server setup and that the virtual software is causing this.  To read all about this mess, go to
https://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?forumID=313&threadID=1261161.

It's a community based forum so you might have to register but it is free.

Ed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after I install .net framework 4.5

I have Crystal 10 installed on a Windows 7 64bit Computer R2 and I was getting the error when trying to open a report in Crystal 10.

I copied the file From: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.5\bin To: C:\Program Files (x86)\Crystal Decisions\Crystal Reports 10

Thank goodness issue resolved.

Comment: Works for Crystal Reports 10

Answer (score 0):

My 'solution' (if you can call it that) was to **not**  use **Crystal Reports Basic for VS 2008**.  I switched to using **Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 2.0**, which comes bundled with VS 2005. I then installed this runtime on the server, and it worked fine.

[image: Image of CR for .NET Framework 2.0 references]

Note the version # of **10.2.3600.0** instead of **10.5.3700.0**.

I don't know why I was experiencing this error with the newer version, but at least now I can get back to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have Crystal 10 installed on a Windows 7 64bit Computer as well as Crystal XI R2 and I was getting the error when trying to open a report in Crystal 10.

I copied the file 
From:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Common\3.5\bin
To:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Crystal Decisions\Crystal Reports 10

Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I install .net framework 4.5

I have Crystal 10 installed on a Windows 7 64bit Computer R2 and I was getting the error when trying to open a report in Crystal 10.

I copied the file From: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.5\bin To: C:\Program Files (x86)\Crystal Decisions\Crystal Reports 10
**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when open a report on a  Windows 10 Pro 64bit Computer.
What I did was copying the file from c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.0\bin to c:\Windows\SysWOW64 and it was resolved.